# Unexpected Bound - Why can't I use something like T extends Collection in this Collector?

Tags: java, generics, types, collections

Hi I have written this custom collector for converting a `List` of elements into a `Multimap`:

```
public class MultiMapCollector implements Collector<Entity,
        Map<String, Collection<String>>, Map<String, Collection<String>>> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<String, Collection<String>>> supplier() {
        return HashMap::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<String, Collection<String>>, Entity> accumulator() {
        return (map, e) -> map.computeIfAbsent(e.getName(),
                k -> new HashSet<>()).add(e.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<String, Collection<String>>> combiner() {
        return (map1, map2) -> {
            map2.keySet().forEach(key -> map1.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(map2.get(key)));
            return map1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<String, Collection<String>>, Map<String, Collection<String>>> finisher() {
        return Collections::unmodifiableMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to pass a `List` or a `Set`.

So instead of `Map<String, Collection<String>>` I want something like `Map<String, V extends Collection<String>>`

But when I do that I get a vague error saying :

```
Unexpected Bounds
```

**What am I doing wrong ?**

I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: I think from a syntax point a view you haven't declared `V` anywhere that I can see.  `public <V> void something( Map<String, V extends Collections<String>> x );` I think might work.

Comment: @markspace Yes, but how do I instantiate the container for eg. `new HashSet<>();` ?

Comment: Are you reinventing `groupingBy(Entity::getName, toCollection(SomeCollection::new))`?

Comment: @Sweeper yes just wanted to see how its implemented. So wanted to write my own collector.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a generic type parameter (let's call it `C`) after the class name, not in the `implements` clause.

Then, add a constructor that takes in a `Supplier<C>` telling you how to create a `C`, and store the supplier somewhere. Replace all the occurrences of `new HashSet<>()` with `get` calls to the supplier instead.

```
class MultiMapCollector<C extends Collection<String>> implements Collector<Entity, Map<String, C>, Map<String, C>> {

     private final Supplier<C> supplier;

     public MultiMapCollector(Supplier<C> supplier) {

         this.supplier = supplier;
     }

    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<String, C>> supplier() {
        return HashMap::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<String, C>, Entity> accumulator() {
        return (map, e) -> map.computeIfAbsent(e.getName(),
            k -> supplier.get()).add(e.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<String, C>> combiner() {
        return (map1, map2) -> {
            map2.keySet().forEach(key -> map1.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> supplier.get()).addAll(map2.get(key)));
            return map1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<String, C>, Map<String, C>> finisher() {
        return Collections::unmodifiableMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        // now you aren't sure whether the collection is ordered or not
        return Set.of();
    }
}
```

Now every time you create a `MultiMapCollector`, you need to pass in a supplier:

```
new MultiMapCollector<>(HashSet::new)
```

If you want it to use a default of `HashSet` when you don't provide anything, add static factory methods and make the constructor private:

```
 public static MultiMapCollector<Set<String>> get() {
     return new MultiMapCollector<>(HashSet::new);
 }

 public static <C extends Collection<String>> MultiMapCollector<C> with(Supplier<C> supplier) {
     return new MultiMapCollector<>(supplier);
 }
```

Just like how `Collectors.groupingBy` is a factory method.

More generally, you can take a full downstream collector instead of just a `Supplier<C>`, and that is what the 2-parameter overload of `Collectors.groupingBy` does. `groupingBy` just handles the grouping, and the downstream collector (the 2nd argument) handles the groups.

Here is a sketch of how you would do this:

```
class MultiMapCollector<R> implements Collector<Entity, Map<String, R>, Map<String, R>> {

     private final Collector<String, R, R> downstream;

     private MultiMapCollector(Collector<String, R, R> downstream) {

         this.downstream = downstream;
     }

     public static MultiMapCollector<Set<String>> get() {
         return new MultiMapCollector<>(Collectors.toSet());
     }

     public static <R> MultiMapCollector<R> with(Collector<String, R, R> downstream) {
         return new MultiMapCollector<>(downstream);
     }

    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<String, R>> supplier() {
        return HashMap::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<String, R>, Entity> accumulator() {
        return (map, e) -> downstream.accumulator().accept(map.computeIfAbsent(e.getName(),
            k -> downstream.supplier().get()), e.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<String, R>> combiner() {
        return (map1, map2) -> {
            map2.keySet().forEach(key -> 
                downstream.combiner().apply(
                    map1.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> downstream.supplier().get()),
                    map2.get(key)
                )
            );
            return map1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<String, R>, Map<String, R>> finisher() {
        return Collections::unmodifiableMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow different implementations of `Collection<String>` to be used as the values of your maps, then you need to define a type parameter for your `MultiMapCollector`. You'll also need to modify the code to accept some sort of object, such as a `Supplier`, that knows how to create instances of the specific collection type.

For example:

```java
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

public class MultiMapCollector<V extends Collection<String>>
    implements Collector<Entity, Map<String, V>, Map<String, V>> {

  private final Supplier<? extends V> valueSupplier;

  public MultiMapCollector(Supplier<? extends V> valueSupplier) {
    this.valueSupplier = valueSupplier;
  }

  @Override
  public Supplier<Map<String, V>> supplier() {
    return HashMap::new;
  }

  @Override
  public BiConsumer<Map<String, V>, Entity> accumulator() {
    return (map, e) -> map.computeIfAbsent(e.getName(), k -> valueSupplier.get()).add(e.getValue());
  }

  @Override
  public BinaryOperator<Map<String, V>> combiner() {
    return (map1, map2) -> {
      for (var entry : map2.entrySet()) {
        map1.merge(
            entry.getKey(),
            entry.getValue(),
            (curValue, newValue) -> {
              curValue.addAll(newValue);
              return curValue;
            });
      }
      return map1;
    };
  }

  @Override
  public Function<Map<String, V>, Map<String, V>> finisher() {
    return Collections::unmodifiableMap;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
    return Set.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
  }
}
```

Note `MultiMapCollector` now has the type parameter `<V extends Collection<String>>`, and that everywhere else in the code where `Collection<String>` was used has been replaced with `V`. And then the constructor accepts a `Supplier<? extends V>` which is used to create instances of `V` in the `accumulator()` consumer.

Also, note I updated your `combiner()` function to make use of `Map#merge(...)`, though that's not strictly necessary.

---

By the way, if you want to actually see how `Collectors.groupingBy(...)` is implemented, then you can always look at the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#L996).